# How to specialize a function for a tuple parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I have the following function:

```
template <typename Functor, typename Arg>
decltype(auto) call(Functor f, Arg &&arg) { // (1)
    // ..
}
```

I would like to create a specialization for the cases when `arg` is a `tuple`. I tried:

```
template <typename Functor, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) call(Functor f, std::tuple<Args...> &&args) { // (2)
    // ..
}
```

Which works on its own, but when both are present, (1) turns out to be a better match even when the argument is a tuple. I'm using clang 3.7 to compile the code.

Comment: the latter is not a specialization, but an overload taking a tuple rvalue, do you pass an rvalue?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki In some cases I want to.

Comment: what I mean is that it's not possible that (1) is preferred to (2), if (2) works without (1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do one level of indirection if you want to spare yourself from writing ugly SFINAE. Instead of tag dispatching, you can also delegate to a class template, but I prefer tags

```
template<typename> class type { };

template <typename Functor, typename Arg>
decltype(auto) call(Functor f, Arg &&arg) {
    return call(f, std::forward<Arg>(arg), type<std::decay_t<Arg>>());
}

template <typename Functor, typename Arg, typename T>
decltype(auto) call(Functor f, Arg &&arg, type<T>) {
    ...
}

template <typename Functor, typename Arg, typename ...T>
decltype(auto) call(Functor f, Arg &&arg, type<std::tuple<T...>>) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice and clear. In real use it woud probably be nice to put `type` and the helper `call`s in an `impl` namespace.

Comment: @JohanLundberg you are right. but then you need to be careful about the order of the call functions, because `type` is not anymore an ADL-hint for finding the other overloads of `call`. EDIT: if you put the calls into the same namespace, that will work, nvm :)

Answer (score 1):

I find that your example does work (and vs2015 agrees)

http://ideone.com/dNTsrf .

The base case is a universal references and it takes both rvalue and rvalues (and references). (Live demo http://ideone.com/kCBv3d)

```
decltype(auto) call(int &&arg) { // (1)
    std::cout << "Base case" << std::endl;
}     
decltype(auto) call(std::tuple<int> &&args) { 
    std::cout << "TTT" << std::endl;
}
/// main:   
call(std::tuple<int>{1}); // TTT
call(2);                  // Base case
std::tuple<int> ti{5};    
call(1,ti);               // Base case (as expected!)
call(1,std::move(ti));    // TTT
```

Note, your overload takes r-value references (not forwarding references), so anything else (lvalue references) will use the base case.

As I understand it, this is all overloading, but a relevant read is this post by Herb Sutter: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: not if that other overload is more specialized and equally viable

Comment: Well the problem is exactly with the case `call(1, ti)`; I don't have the liberty of using std::move because it is called from generic code.

Comment: @TamásSzelei, note that this means that you are in fact not getting move semantics for this case then. If you would like that, you should revise (if possible) the generic code to use `std::forward<>`. It's there for this case exactly.